# Solverstudio: How to add data item using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, solver, pulp

I am using SolverStudio to solve a problem which will require me to create ALOT of Data items in the [Data Items Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCC9t.png)

In the image in the link you would add a data item by entering in the name cell range and optionally index range. Would it be possible to add data items using VBA or something similar as I have ALOT of data items to add so anything that would make adding data items simpler and faster I need.

Any help or advise is welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find out how to do this in the SolverStudio Documentation.

[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6Mba.png)